# how to interact between two electron apps on different machines

Tags: express, electron

suppose i create a express server and host it at 8080 on my machine-1 then i can access http://machine-1-ip:8080/ from any machine within network

if i wrap this api with electron namely app1 and install on machine 1 and create another electron app namely app2 and install it on machine two. is it possible to make request from machine 2 to machine 1 at http://machine-1-ip:8080 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. It's possible if machine two is within the same network.

CORS must be enabled in your express server.(https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cors.html).

Firewall rules of machine 1 should be configured in a way that it takes request from other machines within the network.